# CSS локатор с исключением

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, testng, css-selection

Не могу написать правильно CSS локатор. Ситуация следующая:

```
            <div class="slick-track" role="listbox" style="opacity: 1; width: 4616px; transform: translate3d(-1154px, 0px, 0px);">
                <div class="text-link-slider__slide slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 1154px;">
                    Еда и вино <a href="https://qaz.com" tabindex="-1">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-link-slider__slide slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00" style="width: 1154px;">
                    Безжалостный удар по ценам <a href="https://qaz.com" tabindex="0">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-link-slider__slide slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide01" style="width: 1154px;">
                    Еда и вино <a href="https://qaz.com" tabindex="-1">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-link-slider__slide slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 1154px;">
                    Безжалостный удар по ценам <a href="https://qaz.com" tabindex="-1">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Это баннер, который переключается каждые 2 сек. Активный элемент помечен `slick-active`
мне нужны 2 и 3 элементы.

Мой вариант локатора

````
div.slick-track>div.text-link-slider__slide.slick-slide:not([slick-cloned]):not([data-slick-index*='2'])```
````

но он не фильтрует по `slick-cloned`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.slick-track>div.text-link-slider__slide.slick-slide:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)
```